# Scrolling panel with a list

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to create a view with a panel at the top that contains some HTML and beneath that I want to put a list. When the user scrolls the panel I want the whole thing to scroll, so that the top panel is scrolled of the screen and the user can browse to the list.

I can't seem to figure out the right layout setup to make this work. Basic code is as follows:

```
Ext.define("myApp.view.myView", {
  extend: 'Ext.Panel',
  config: {
    title: 'Nieuw',
    fullscreen: true,
    scrollable: true,
    items: [
      {
        xtype: 'panel',
        html: 'my content',
      },
      {
        xtype: 'my_list',
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

The my_list is a simple Ext.List class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some simple things to do:

1. Config your `myApp.view.myView` with: `extend: 'Ext.Container'` and `layout: 'vbox'`
2. Config your list with `scrollable: false`

Hope it helps.

Comment: That, together with scrollable: true on myView did the trick. Thanks! I'm really starting to like this framework.